# Cycling through an array of variables in Processing

Tags: arrays, processing, typography

I am trying to create a program in where you press a keyboard character and is then display in 6 different fonts (inside six different colored squares). I'm showing six fonts at a time, but I want to be able to alternate in between fonts while I left click with the mouse. As of now, right clicking converts the font that's underneath the mouse pointer into italics.

My question is: how can I make an array of PFont variables, so for when I left click on a "character"; I can cycle thru some fonts i.e. (Helvetica, Futura, Optima).

My code is below:

```js
boolean button1 = false;
boolean button2 = false;
boolean button3 = false;
boolean button4 = false;
boolean button5 = false;
boolean button6 = false;

int x1 =0;
int y1 =0;
int w1 = 400;
int h1 = 600;

int x2 = 400;
int y2 = 0;
int w2 = 400;
int h2 = 600;

int x3 = 800;
int y3 = 0;
int w3 = 400;
int h3 = 600;

int x4 = 0;
int y4 = 600;
int w4 = 400;
int h4 = 600;

int x5 = 400;
int y5 = 600;
int w5 = 400;
int h5 = 600;

int x6 = 800;
int y6 = 600;
int w6 = 400;
int h6 = 600;

String hel_reg = "Helvetica.vlw";
String din_reg = "DIN.vlw";
String did_reg = "Didot.vlw";
String roc_reg = "Rockwell.vlw";
String bel_reg = "Bell.vlw";
String sab_reg = "Sabon.vlw";

String hel_itl = "Helvetica_itl.vlw";
String din_itl = "DIN_itl.vlw";
String did_itl = "Didot_itl.vlw";
String roc_itl = "Rockwell_itl.vlw";
String bel_itl = "Bell_itl.vlw";
String sab_itl = "Sabon_itl.vlw";

String fut_reg = "Futura.vlw";
String opt_reg = "Optima.vlw";
String cla_reg = "Clarendon.vlw";
String uni_reg = "Unit_Slab_Pro.vlw";
String mrs_reg = "Mrs_Eaves.vlw";
String cas_reg = "Caslon.vlw";

String fut_itl = "Futura_Italics.vlw";

String name = "FranklinGothic-Demi-30.vlw";

String letters = "";

PFont Helvetica;
PFont DIN;
PFont Didot;
PFont Rockwell;
PFont Bell;
PFont Sabon;

PFont Helvetica_Italics;
PFont DIN_Italics;
PFont Didot_Italics;
PFont Rockwell_Italics;
PFont Bell_Italics;
PFont Sabon_Italics;

PFont Futura;
PFont Optima;
PFont Clarendon;
PFont Unit_Slab;
PFont Mrs_Eaves;
PFont Caslon;

PFont Futura_Italics;

PFont Franklin_Gothic;


void setup() {
  size(1200, 1300);
  Helvetica = loadFont(hel_reg);
  DIN = loadFont(din_reg);
  Didot = loadFont(did_reg);
  Rockwell = loadFont(roc_reg);
  Bell = loadFont(bel_reg);
  Sabon = loadFont(sab_reg);

  Helvetica_Italics = loadFont(hel_itl);
  DIN_Italics = loadFont(din_itl);
  Didot_Italics = loadFont(did_itl);
  Rockwell_Italics = loadFont(roc_itl);
  Bell_Italics = loadFont(bel_itl);
  Sabon_Italics = loadFont(sab_itl);

  Futura = loadFont(fut_reg);
  Optima = loadFont(opt_reg);
  Clarendon = loadFont(cla_reg);
  Unit_Slab = loadFont(uni_reg);
  Mrs_Eaves = loadFont(mrs_reg);
  Caslon = loadFont(cas_reg);

  Futura_Italics = loadFont(fut_itl);

  Franklin_Gothic = loadFont(name);
}

void draw() {
  noStroke();
  fill(176, 116, 143);
  rect(x1, y1, w1, h1);

  fill(135, 184, 194);
  rect(x2, y2, w2, h2);

  fill(225, 205, 109);
  rect(x3, y3, w3, h3);

  fill(230, 111, 83);
  rect(x4, y4, w4, h4);

  fill(64, 78, 87);
  rect(x5, y5, w5, h5);

  fill(245, 242, 238);
  rect(x6, y6, w6, h6 );

  fill(117, 172, 151);
  rect(0, 1200, 1200, 100 );

  //stroke(245, 242, 238);
  //strokeWeight(2);

  //line(400, 1200, 400, 1300);
  //line(800, 1200, 800, 1300);



  if (button1) {
    fill(225, 205, 109);
    textFont(Helvetica_Italics);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 200, 400 );
  } else {
    fill(225, 205, 109);
    textFont(Helvetica);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 200, 400 );
  }

  if (button2) {
    fill(64, 78, 87);
    textFont(Didot_Italics);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 600, 400 );
  } else {
    fill(64, 78, 87);
    textFont(Didot);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 600, 400 );
  }

  if (button3) {
    fill(176, 116, 143);
    textFont(Bell_Italics);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 1000, 400);
  } else {
    fill(176, 116, 143);
    textFont(Bell);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 1000, 400);
  }

  if (button4) {
    fill(245, 242, 238);
    textFont(DIN_Italics);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 200, 1000);
  } else {
    fill(245, 242, 238);
    textFont(DIN);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 200, 1000);
  }

  if (button5) {
    fill(230, 111, 83);
    textFont(Rockwell_Italics);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 600, 1000 );
  } else {
    fill(230, 111, 83);
    textFont(Rockwell);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 600, 1000 );
  }

  if (button6) {
    fill(135, 184, 194);
    textFont(Sabon_Italics);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 1000, 1000);
  } else {
    fill(135, 184, 194);
    textFont(Sabon);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(key, 1000, 1000);
  }

  textAlign(CENTER);
  textFont(Franklin_Gothic);
  fill(245, 242, 238);

  text("HELVETICA", 200, 1241.58);
  text("DIN", 200, 1277.5);
  text("DIDOT", 600, 1241.58);
  text("ROCKWELL", 600, 1277.5);
  text("BELL", 1000, 1241.58);
  text("SABON", 1000, 1277.5);
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX > x1 && mouseX < x1+w1 && mouseY > y1 && mouseY < y1+h1 && mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    button1 = !button1;
  }
  if (mouseX > x2 && mouseX < x2+w2 && mouseY > y2 && mouseY < y2+h2 && mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    button2 = !button2;
  }
  if (mouseX > x3 && mouseX < x3+w3 && mouseY > y3 && mouseY < y3+h3 && mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    button3 = !button3;
  }
  if (mouseX > x4 && mouseX < x4+w4 && mouseY > y4 && mouseY < y4+h4 && mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    button4 = !button4;
  }
  if (mouseX > x5 && mouseX < x5+w5 && mouseY > y5 && mouseY < y5+h5 && mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    button5 = !button5;
  }
  if (mouseX > x6 && mouseX < x6+w6 && mouseY > y6 && mouseY < y6+h6 && mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    button6 = !button6;
  }


  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
  }
}
```

You might not be able to run the code because I have vlw files on a data folder. I don't know how to include that in here.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create an array (or an [`ArrayList`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html)) and add your fonts to it.

**Step 2:** Create a variable that keeps track of which index of the array holds the current font.

**Step 3:** Increment that variable whenever you want to change the font being used.

Comment: How can I create an array using PFont?

Comment: `PFont []  fonts = new PFont [numberOfFonts];`  or an Arraylist `ArrayList <PFont> fonts = newArrayList <PFont>();` - - - PFont is an object (class) as any other so u can just use it as any other :)